# How to ignore an potentially broken disk that freezes installation process of ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: boot, grub2

the titles is clear. I guess my 10 years old classic hard drive causes a problem that  prevent installation of Ubuntu OS. the installation process get stuck after the "checking disk", and even if a cancel checking disks (by `Ctrl+C`) it again get stuck forever. I tested multiple USB drive and Muliple OS (Centos) they all fail to install. I have no idea but the most probable candidate in my opinion is the old disk (I have  a Windows 10 ins). and even I added 'nomodeset' to grub boot option, again it get stuck. so, how to ignore or disable this disk ?

I will greatly appreciate any other recommendations to resolve this problem.

**update**:
I disabled splash from grub to see logs, the installation get stuck and the last log is :

```
[  187.862414] systemd[1]: inserted module 'autofs4'
```

Comment: The checking disk is itself checking its installation media. Are you using DVD or USB? Did you verify the download before putting it on DVD/USB? When booted to the installation media, you could use the `Disks` app to look at the HDD SMART data.